VBA macro to set password to pdf files
I am trying to create multiple documents from word mail merge.  Want to save them as both .docx as well as .pdf with password to open the file.
While I could successfully create word documents with password, the PDF is not asking for password.
I tried the below code.
Set singleDoc = ActiveDocument                                           ' Identify the ActiveDocument (foremost doc after running the MailMerge) as "singleDoc"
        singleDoc.SaveAs2 _
            FileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
                masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFileName").Value & ".docx", _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument                                      ' Save "singleDoc" as a word docx with the details provided in the DocFolderPath and DocFileName fields in the MailMerge data
        singleDoc.SaveAs2 _
            FileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
                masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFileName").Value & ".pdf", _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
            'Password:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("FilePassword").Value                                               ' Save "singleDoc" as a word docx with the details provided in the DocFolderPath and DocFileName fields in the MailMerge data
         singleDoc.Close False                                                    ' Close "singleDoc", the variable "singleDoc" can now be used for the next record when created

I also tried the option to set the password to active document
sigleDoc.Password = "Password123"
While this works for word documents, does not work for pdf. files.
Appreciate any help.
Tried setting password to the active document.

You cannot create a password protected PDF file by VBA

Thanks, that is what I figured so far.
